# How to assign users for joomla photo gallery

Tags: php, joomla, gallery, photo

I want to create a photo gallery it shoud be assign for specific user to view. ex: Uploda a few photos it can be show only that user after login him/her account

Answer (score 0):

You can create a photogallery using joom gallery http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/5481 and also you can set user permission through component admin by just going to Configuration manager.